# Can't figure out the mappings for native types with JNA

Tags: java, macos, jna

I am trying to call native functions from the ApplicationServices framework on a mac using JNA.  However, the return type of the function I want to use as wel as its parameters are as far as I can tell unsimiliar to anything in Java, and I don't know how to map them.

The function I want to use:

```
CFArrayRef CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
CGWindowListOption option,
CGWindowID relativeToWindow);
```

I have no idea how to map any of these.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the rococoa project (http://rococoa.java.net), which addresses mapping various types specific to OSX.